# Having error in the attempt of web-scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, export-to-csv

I've been trying to get data and export to CSV files. I use 2 urls to get data from several pages by setting main URL page and second URL main page which I have imported the following of these:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
import csv

def get_page(url):
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    mainpage = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    return mainpage
mainpage = get_page(www.mainwebsite.com)
mainpage_parser = BeautifulSoup(mainpage,'html.parser')
secondpage = get_page('www.secondmainwebsite.com')
secondpage_parser = BeautifulSoup(secondpage,'html.parser')
```

The patterns of the data are the same such as Title, Address; thus, the code I use is "find" or "find_all" in each class; for example,

```
try:
    name = page_parser.find("h1",{"class":"xxx"}).find("a").get_text()
print(name)
except:
print(name)
```

Which it worked. However, I couldn't get the "lat" and "lon" from url link in this html class:

```
<img class="aaa" alt="map" data-track-id="static-map" width="97" height="142" src="https://www.website.com/aaaaaaa&map=StreetMapHD&width=194&height=284&lat=18.832687&lon=98.998473&level=15& returnImage=true">
```

The code I'm trying to get latitude and longitude is:

```
   for gps in secondpage_parser.find_all('img',{"class":"aaa"}, src=True):
      parsed_url = urlparse(gps['src'])
      mykeys = ['lat', 'lon']
      gpslocation = [parse_qs(parsed_url.query)[k][0] for k in mykeys]
   print(gps['src'], parse_qs(parsed_url.params))
```

But it has Name Error on the "print(gps['src'], parse_qs(parsed_url.params))" line which it indicates "NameError: name 'gps' is not defined"

I would like to know which part here I have the mistake or how should I fix it. Please help.

Comment: can you write in a:
print(gps['src']) and see what happens? I'm guessing that gps['src'] isn't producing a urlstring which is causing this bug

Comment: @JakeBourne Thank you, I've tried. But it resulted in the same error indicating that gps is not defined. However, I'm stuck as well what could be the bug.

Comment: so what is the output of print(gps['src'])?

Comment: It is "NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-50592c0e909a> in <module>() ---->  print(gps['src'], parse_qs(parsed_url.params)) NameError: name 'gps' is not defined." I might say sorry if this looks quite messy.

Comment: sorry, probably not being clear, run this code

 ` for gps in secondpage_parser.find_all('img',{"class":"aaa"}, src=True):
      print(gps['src'])`

Comment: I've tried. But there is no output when I run. Thank you so much for your  suggestion. I'm worried about it as well.

Comment: alright, try print(gps) in that formula, that should produce a url hopefully